# Obtener tamaño total de ficheros de un usuario linux

Tags: linux, bash

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo obtener el tamaño total en bytes y luego pasarlo a una medida legible por humano (kb, mg, gb) de todos los ficheros de un usuario específico. Estoy probando esto:

```sh
    ALL_FILES=$(find / -user $NAME -type f 2>>./.tmp.txt)
    TOTAL_SIZE=$(echo $ALL_FILES | du -s | cut -f 1)
```

Esta claro que eso de ahí no funciona ni de lejos, da igual que usuario pase a $NAME, siempre me devuelve el mismo valor.

Gracias.

Comment: Recuerda que `du` tiene el parámetro `-h` para "human".

Comment: Gracias,  por el recordatorio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con `awk`.

```
find <carpeta> -type f -user $USER -printf "%s\n" | awk '{total_size+=$0}END{print "tamaño total: " total_size " B"}'
```

Lo que hace `-printf "%s\n"` es imprimir únicamente el tamaño del archivo en bytes seguído de un salto de línea (mismo qe utilizaremos para el comando siguiente).

Después, usaremos `awk` para acumular los tamaños de los archivos obtenidos por `find`, en la variable `total_size`. Al final, lo imprimiremos.

Comment: Lo probaré ahora mismo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
find / -user $NAME -type f -printf "%s\n" 2>/dev/null | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

**du -s** está calculando el espacio usado en el directorio actual, no la lista de ficheros.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Te agradecería muchísimo si me puedes explicar que hace el código.

Comment: Creo que la primera parte del find ya la tienes clara.

-printf "%s\n" imprime el tamaño (en bytes) de cada fichero encontrado.

2>/dev/null descarta los mensajes de error.

El comando paste concatena en serie utilizando + como delimitador, es decir, genera una lista al estilo 10+20+34 ...
Y, por último, bc se encarga de realizar la suma recibida.